# Deadlock on a table which has a view in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-deadlocks

We have a table in SQL server on which there exists a view. The view is being read by a job every 10 seconds. Another job tries to update the underlying table and gets a deadlock exception. Can reading from a view also locks the table such that it can result in a deadlock?

Comment: Obviously yes - cos you are having it happen :) deadlocks are fairly complex scenarios, so I suggest doing some reading about them to improve your general understanding. Especially as I see you've asked other questions about them.

Comment: [Does a Simple Select Query Acquire Locks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40987/does-a-simple-select-query-acquire-locks)

Comment: Use NOLOCK in view to read dirty data. but it not lock the table while reading.

Comment: i.e. don't use `nolock` instead there are a lot of things you can do to reduce the chances of deadlock.